# Как не нарушать принцип DRY в представлении? Лучшие практики

Tags: python, django, рефакторинг

Существует представление `OrderItemEdit`:

```
class OrderItemEdit(View):
def get(self, request, number, order_item_id):

    # Если в сесси есть номер заказа
    if 'new_order' in request.session.keys():
        order_number = request.session['new_order_number']

        # Проверка number
        # Если url number совпадает со значение в сессии
        if number == order_number:

            # Проверка order_item_id

            order = Order.objects.get(number=order_number)
            order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(id=order_item_id)

            # Если найден order_item с таким id
            if order_item:
                order_item = order_item[0]

                # Если order_item соответствует текущему order
                if order_item in order_items:
                    format = order_item.format
                    border = order_item.border

                    form = OrderItemEditForm(initial={
                        'format': format,
                        'border': border,
                    })

                    context = {}
                    context['form'] = form
                    context['order_number'] = order_number
                    context['order_item_id'] = order_item_id
                    return render(request, 'store/new_order_item_edit.html', context)

                else:
                    return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

            else:
                return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

                # Если url number не совпадает со значением в сессии
        elif number != order_number:
            return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

    else:
        return redirect('/order/new/')

def post(self, request, number, order_item_id):

    # Если в сесси есть номер заказа
    if 'new_order' in request.session.keys():
        order_number = request.session['new_order_number']

        # Проверка number
        # Если url number совпадает со значение в сессии
        if number == order_number:

            # Проверка order_item_id

            order = Order.objects.get(number=order_number)
            order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order)
            order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(id=order_item_id)

            # Если найден order_item с таким id
            if order_item:
                order_item = order_item[0]

                # Если order_item соответствует текущему order
                if order_item in order_items:
                    form = OrderItemEditForm(request.POST)

                    # Если форма валидна
                    if form.is_valid():
                        format = form.cleaned_data.get('format')
                        border = form.cleaned_data.get('border')

                        order_item.format = format
                        order_item.border = border
                        order_item.save()

                        return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

                    else:
                        return redirect('/order/{}/edit/item/{}/'.format(order_number, order_item.id))

                else:
                    return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

            else:
                return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

        # Если url number не совпадает со значением в сессии
        elif number != order_number:
            return redirect('/order/{}/edit/'.format(order_number))

    else:
        return redirect('/order/new/')
```

И в `get`, и в `post` запросах есть одинаковые проверки, части кода. Также и в других представлениях некоторые части кода повторяются. Хотел бы уточнить: как вынести проверки и другие части кода так, чтобы это было структурно правильно, повторяемо и не нарушало принцип don't repeat yourself.

**Обновлено 1**
Пришла на ум идея создать shortcuts.py и вынести туда проверки. Например:

*shortcuts.py*

```
def check_session_new_order(session):    
   if 'new_order' in session.keys():
       return True
   else:
       return False
```

*views.py*

```
if check_session_new_order(request.session):
        order_number = request.session['new_order_number']
        ...
```

Не уверен что мой подход корректен, но все же оставлю это здесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, ваш вариант один из часто используемых. Так же можно вынести его в отдельный пакет, в котором держать модули логики, и импортировать для работы.
[Вот тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPo29ygf0wA), например, более подробно об архитектуре. Но вкратце - всё то же, что я сказал выше.